# mapreduce distance calculation in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, parallel-processing

Is there a distance calculation implementation using hadoop map/reduce. I am trying to calculate a distance between a given set of points.

Looking for any resources.

**Edit**

This is a very intelligent solution. I have tried some how like the first algorithm, and I get almost what I was looking for. I am not concerned about optimizing the program at the moment, but my problem was the dist(X,Y) function was not working. When I got all the points on the reducer, I was unable to go through all the points on an Iterator and calculate the distance. Someone on stackoverflow.com told me that the Iterator on hadoop is different than the normal JAVA Iterator, i am not sure about that. But if i can find a simple way to go through the Iterator on my dist() function, i can use your second algorithm to optimize.

```
//This is your code and I am refering to that code too, just to make my point clear.
map(x,y) {
  for i in 1:N #number of points
    emit(i, (x,y)) //i did exactly like this

    reduce (i, X)
    p1 = X[i]
    for j in i:N
      // here is my problem, I can't get the values from the Iterator.
      emit(dist(X[i], X[j]))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "distance between a set of points"? The shortest path?

Comment: What does your input data look like? You should explain what you're working with more so we don't have to guess. :D

Comment: i have a comma separated numbers in .csv format, 12,14,3,4,8,6,7,5, when i read the file in hadoop, they represent points in two dimensions like (12,14) (3,4) (8,6) (7,5). I did that on my mapper method. This can be any number of points. then my question is i want to implement a reducer so that i will be able to calculate the distance between all the point. from the sample points above i will calculate 6 distances.

Thanks,

Comment: Presently writing one as a simple demonstration of MapReduce for geospatial calculations for a paper, though it's in qizmt - not hadoop.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter whether i use hadoop or qizmt as far as it is mapreduce. What i am looking for is the idea of doing the calculation in parallel.

Any idea or concept will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do a self join on that data set. In hive that would look like, more or less

```
select dist(P1.x,P1.y,P2.x, P2.y) from points P1 join points P2 on (True) where P1.x < P2.x or (P1.x = P2.x and P1.y < P2.y)
```

The function dist would need to be implemented using other hive functions or written in Java and added as a UDF. Also I am not sure about the True constant but you can write 0=0 to the same effect. The where clause is to avoid computing the same distances twice or 0 distances. The question is: would hive optimize this the way you can do programming carefully in hadoop? I am not sure. This is a sketch in hadoop

```
map(x,y) {
  for i in 1:N #number of points
     emit(i, (x,y))

reduce (i, X)
  p1 = X[i]
  for j in i:N
     emit(dist(X[i], X[j]))
```

For this to work you need X to get to the reducer sorted in some order, for instance by x and then by y using secondary sort keys (that do not affect the grouping). This way every reducer gets a copy of all the points and works on a column of the distance matrix you are trying to generate. The memory requirements are minimal. You could trade some communication for memory by re-organizing the computation so that every reducer computes a square submatrix of the final matrix, knowing only two subsets of the points and calculating the distances among all of them. To achieve this, you need to make explicit the order of your points, say you are storing i, x, y

```
map(i,x,y) {
  for j in 1:N/k #k is size of submatrix
     emit((i/k, j), ("row", (x,y)))
     emit((j, i/k), ("col", (x,y)))

reduce ((a,b), Z)
  split Z in rows X and cols Y
  for x in X
     for y in Y
     emit(dist(x,y))
```

In this case you can see that the map phase emits only 2*N*N/k points, whereas the previous algorithm emitted N^2. Here we have (N/k)^2 reducers vs N for the other one. Each reducer has to hold k values in memory (using the secondary key technique to have all the rows get to the reducer before all the columns), vs only 2 before. So you see there are tradeoffs and for the second algorithm you can use the parameter k for perf tuning.

Comment: So this is now an iterator problem. I think if you look at the standard wordcount example, there is a loop using an iterator over the reduced values in the reducer. It looks pretty standard to me, you declare it as Iterator<T> and call next() and hasNext() on it, see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount If you could be more specific as to what happens when you try and get your values instead of what you are expecting, maybe I could be more helpful. Errors? The wrong values? Nothing? Can you share the declaration for the Iterator and the lines of code where you access it?

Comment: Also I think you edited away the definition of your problem, which takes away from the value of this conversation for other people. You are not supposed to edit questions this way. Adding clarifications is fine and I thank you for the comments on my solution, but please restore the detailed problem def and example.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not sound like a good fit for map-reduce since you're not really able to break it into pieces and calculate each piece independently. If you could have a separate program that generates the complete graph of your points as a list (x1,y1,x2,y2) then you could do a straightforward map to get the distance.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but i don't understand a separate program to generate the complete graph of the points. Can you make this more clear so that i can apply your idea to my program.

Comment: Well you would want a program to create every unique combination of the points. You can sort of say that each point is a node in a graph and you want to generate the complete graph (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of the points. I don't know of any good way to do this with mapreduce because every point needs to be aware of every other point. You're better off just using a nested loop.