# Unexplained Java Hashmap Behavior

Tags: java, hadoop

In the code below, I am creating a hashmap to store objects called Datums, which contain a String (location) and a count. Unfortunately, the code is giving very strange behavior.

```
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            Random r = new Random();
            FSDataOutputStream fsdos = fs.create(new Path("error/" + r.nextInt(1000000)));

            HashMap<String, Datum> datums = new HashMap<String, Datum>();
            while (itrtr.hasNext()) {
                Datum next = itrtr.next();
                synchronized (datums) {
                    if (!datums.containsKey(next.location)) {
                        fsdos.writeUTF("INSERTING: " + next + "\n");
                        datums.put(next.location, next);
                    } else {
                    } // skit those that are already indexed 
                }
            }
            for (Datum d : datums.values()) {
                fsdos.writeUTF("PRINT DATUM VALUES: " + d.toString() + "\n");
            }
```

The hashmap has Strings as keys.

Here is the output I get in the error files (example):

```
INSERTING: (test.txt,3)

INSERTING: (test2.txt,1)

PRINT DATUM VALUES: (test.txt,3)

PRINT DATUM VALUES: (test.txt,3)

The correct output for the print should be:
INSERTING: (test.txt,3)

INSERTING: (test2.txt,1)

PRINT DATUM VALUES: (test.txt,3)

PRINT DATUM VALUES: (test2.txt,1)
```

What is happening to the Datum with test2.txt as its location? Why is it getting replaced with test.txt??

Basically, I should never see the same location twice. (that is what the !datums.containsKey is checking for). Unfortunately, I'm getting very strange behavior.

This is on Hadoop, by the way, in a reducer.

**I tried putting the synchronized here in case it was running in multiple threads, which, to my knowledge, it isn't. Still, the same thing happens.**

Comment: I suggest you debug the code to see when/where the map is being corrupted.  It is not obvious from the code you have here.

Comment: I don't have Hadoop experience, but would this code be called from multiple threads? If so, you may be running into concurrency issues with HashMap. Try substituting a ConcurrentHashMap and see if that affects the results. Also, change your if !containsKey / put to use CHM's putIfAbsent method.

Comment: no the map is not a field it is in method stack only it can not be modified by another thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484562/636009) Hadoop's iterator always returns the same object, instead of creating a new object to return each time around the loop.

So, holding onto references to the object returned by the iterator is not valid and will produce surprising results. You'll need to copy the data to a new object:

```
        while (itrtr.hasNext()) {
            Datum next = itrtr.next();
            // copy any values from the Datum to a fresh instance
            Datum insert = new Datum(next.location, next.value);
            if (!datums.containsKey(insert.location)) {
                datums.put(insert.location, insert);
            }
        }
```

Here is a reference to the [Hadoop Reducer documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html) which confirms this:

> The framework will **reuse** the key and value objects that are passed
>   into the reduce, therefore the application should clone the objects
>   they want to keep a copy of.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I want to really also thank JosefN for his answer too. I think he was also correct but this answer solved the problem. Thanks also to everybody else who helped. You saved the day!

Comment: I'm just so used to the way I typically program in Java, that I didn't think that Hadoop would have such strange behavior. It never occurred to me that it would do things this way, but it makes total sense. I did look up the documentation (worked on this for 2 hours to find this bug), but I didn't catch this.

Comment: It definitely violates the Principle of Least Astonishment.

Answer (score 2):

it is not problem of the map but of the code
datums.put(next.location, next); inserts as value reference that is later chnaged :)
that is why at the end all values in the map are the same equal to last processed datum in the map

Comment: That would mean that the latest input was outputted, not the first, right?

Comment: it could be in differnet part of code, normaly copy of object reference is passed so Datum next = itrtr.next() should not be problem but question is how next() is implemented. It needs whole code to analyze.

Comment: It's coming from Hadoop iterator. You're just given the iterator in the reducer. It comes into you as a parameter. I have posted the whole code.

Comment: Is it possible the Hadoop iterator is returning the same object each time, and merely mutating the contents? That would cause the problem @JosefN suggested. Add a copy constructor to your Datums, and make a defensive copy of them before you put them into the map.

Comment: At least according to the above-linked answer, you were correct that the objects were being mutated. I've removed my previous comments.