# Second iteration - values stays the same

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator

I am working on a mapreduce program using hadoop.
I have this part of code in my reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<TextLongWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    long word1count = 0;
    List<TextLongWritable> cache = new ArrayList<TextLongWritable>();

    String decade = key.toString().split("\t")[0];
    String word1 = key.toString().split("\t")[1];

    for (TextLongWritable val : values) {
        if (val.getWord().equals("*")){
            word1count += val.getCount();
            continue;
        }
        cache.add(val);
        log.info("***Reducer*** Word1: " + word1 + "  Word2: " + val.getWord());
    }

    context.write(key, new Text("" + word1count));

    for (TextLongWritable value : cache) {
        if (value.getWord().equals("*")){
            continue;
        }
        log.info("***Reducer*** Word1: " + word1 + "  Word2: " + value.getWord());
        context.write(new Text(decade + "\t" + value.getWord()), new Text(word1 + " " + value.getCount() + "\t" + word1count));
    }

}
```

First, I am using caching as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111248/iterate-twice-on-values) in order to iterate twice on values.

My problem is that in the second loop, all values stays the same. For example if I have a list with the words `one` `two` `three`. Lets say the key is `1900    test`, so that `word1 = "test"`.

The **first** logger output will be:

```
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: one
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: two
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: three
```

But the **second** logger output will be:

```
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: one
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: one
***Reducer*** Word1: test  Word2: one
```

The value stays the same for some reason.
What am I doing wrong here? Does it have something to do with hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by referring to [this](http://www.roman10.net/2012/08/13/hadoop-reducer-iterable-how-to-iterate-twice/) page. I actually first went over all these cases, where this case is the *second wrong example* in that page.

Some explanation on what is happening here in [managing iterator in mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481914/manupulating-iterator-in-mapreduce) post.

So what I had to do is to make a deep copy of my value before adding it to `cache`.

For completion here is my working code:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<TextLongWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    long word1count = 0;
    List<TextLongWritable> cache = new ArrayList<TextLongWritable>();

    String decade = key.toString().split("\t")[0];
    String word1 = key.toString().split("\t")[1];

    for (TextLongWritable val : values) {
        if (val.getWord().equals("*")){
            word1count += val.getCount();
            continue;
        }
        TextLongWritable val_copy = new TextLongWritable(val.getWord(),val.getCount());
        cache.add(val_copy);
    }

    context.write(key, new Text("" + word1count));

    for (TextLongWritable value : cache) {
        context.write(new Text(decade + "\t" + value.getWord()), new Text(word1 + " " + value.getCount() + "\t" + word1count));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop caches the same object during deserialization due to GC overhead. You have to clone or deep copy your `TextLongWritable` in order to put it into a collection.